# Sending POST request to DRF from React locally works fine but getting 404 error when React is on server

Tags: reactjs, apache, django-rest-framework, rest

I have a react app for frontend and Django for backend. I am currently running the django app in the remote server and if I do POST request on it from Postman or from localhost it works fine. But when I deployed react app on the server and do a POST request, I get 404 error. Does anyone knows why that happens?

Edit:
Here is how i am sending my post request to django with axios.

```
const handleSend = () =>{
        const message = {
            name:name,
            email:email,
            description: description
        }
        
        axios.post("api/messages/", message).then((res) => {
            if(res.statusText === "Created"){
                setPage("thankyou");
            }
        });
    }
```

I have a proxy set up in the package.json file as (Example.com is the django server currently running in my apache server.)

```
"proxy": "http://example.com",
```

Comment: What is the url react is using?

Comment: Where is your code?  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research and debugging errors I was finally able to send HTTP request from React to Django on the web server.

I was sending POST request from HTTPS to HTTP which caused the 404 error, so I added an SSL certificate for Django and I also used XMLHttpRequest instead of Axios. Here's my modified handleSend function. Hope this helps someone in the future.

```
 const handleSend = () => {
    const message = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      description: description,
    };
    function reqListener() {
      if (req.status === 201) {
        setPage("thankyou");
      }
    }
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
    req.open("POST", "https://example.com/api/messages/", true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    req.send(JSON.stringify(message));
  };
```